# How do I turn off all the pop-ups in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, deployment, popup, mdapideploy, popover

Lightning these days has so many pop-up messages - notifications from Salesforce for this and that and then there's the in-app notices too. All this is fine and well when you're in the org as you can just close them, but our problem is that we have multiple orgs running the same code, and when we do a deploy we use MDAPI and push the deploy to all orgs. The deploy process logs into each org, and here's where the pop-ups cause a problem - if during the deploy the process encounters a pop-up it stops the deploy as it waits.
It would be great if we could somehow turn them all off at the start of our deploy, then turn them on again once it completes. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have some kind of automation that requires you to log into the org?

Comment: Yes we do - there are settings and setup tasks etc